# How to make an button background be composed of two images on Android?

Tags: android

I am looking to have a button's background be composed of a backround image, with another image overlayed on top. I do not need the button to have any text.

I have tried the following approach:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
```

**button_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background_image" android:gravity="center"></bitmap>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/foreground_image" android:gravity="center"></bitmap>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

However, when I do this, the foreground image is stretched to the size of the background image, even though I am specifying gravity to center.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an imagebutton with background image, like this:

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image" android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/foreground_image"></ImageButton>
```

Comment: I think the src and background attributes need to be switched around, otherwise it worked perfectly!

Comment: Hey Raul, maybe yes, didn't tried in Eclipse to see what it looks like, but did this before in my own applications and worked good.